# How to compose "variables" in the animate package within the multiframe command?

Tags: animate, variable

I am using the `\multiframe` command to create a loop
`\multiframe{54}{i=1+2 }`, starts the loop at i = 1 , increases i by increment of 2, and 54 times

Within the loop, you can use `\i` to refer to the current value of `i` and I would like to have `\2i` to have the even numbers, is that even possible ?
I tried adding another variable `{i=1+2, j=2+2}` but it seems you can only use i ?

Comment: You can use iA, iB .... or anything that starts with i (i for integer) for variable name. see the documentation of animate package page 5

Comment: Yes thank you, the syntax is eg: {iA=1+2,iB=2+2 } to get odd and even numbers